# Please help me understand code under "handleEvent" method below in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
< button id = "elem" > Click me < /button>

  <
  script >
  class Menu {
    handleEvent(event) {
      // mousedown -> onMousedown
      let method = 'on' + event.type[0].toUpperCase() + event.type.slice(1);
      this[method](event);
    }

    onMousedown() {
      elem.innerHTML = "Mouse button pressed";
    }

    onMouseup() {
      elem.innerHTML += "...and released.";
    }
  }

let menu = new Menu();
elem.addEventListener('mousedown', menu);
elem.addEventListener('mouseup', menu); <
/script>
```

Could someone please help me understand what's going in this section of the code? Thank you.

```
 handleEvent(event) {
       // mousedown -> onMousedown
       let method = 'on' + event.type[0].toUpperCase() + event.type.slice(1);
       this[method](event);
    }
```

Comment: Which bit don't you understand?

Comment: What don't you understand about it? (And I really, really, wouldn't write code like that since it isn't the 1990s and we have good support for `addEventListener` now).

Comment: *"what's going in this section of the code"* - The first line builds a string value.  The second line uses that string value as the name of a function to be executed and executes that function.

Comment: I am a noob trying to learn events via javascript.info website and they don't clearly explain what's going on in the code I posted above. Here's the link: https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events
I don't understand what you get when you do 'on' + event.type[0].toUpperCase() + event.type.slice(1) and this[method](event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
event.type[0].toUpperCase()  -- this will return first character of your event name in upper case.(e.g. for submit event, it will return `S` )

event.type.slice(1) -- this will return you all characters of event name except first character.  (e.g. for submit event , it will return `ubmit`)
```

Then you are concatinating above with `on`.

After that in last line of function, you are calling derived function which you generated from above string e.g. `onSubmit`.

In your case, it looks like you are capturing `mousedown` event & then converting that event to `onMousedown()` string & calling your `onMousedown()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is exactly what I was trying to understand. You explained it beautifully. I got it now. Thank you.